# How can I set indexed value to change the color of each column header and how to set color from API request?

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I want to set the color of the different columns headers in excel file so how can I set the indexed value to set the color of each column header and suppose if I am getting  4 different colors in hexadecimal(#FFF) format from API request then, how can I set those color into 4 different column headers.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

class CreateXSSFColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   String rgbS = "FFF000";
   byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS); // get byte array from hex string
   XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null); //IndexedColorMap has no usage until now. So it can be set null.

   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
   cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("yellow");
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear where you problem is. Your showed code creates one `XSSFColor` from hex string and creates one `XSSFCellStyle` having that `XSSFColor` as the fill color. Then it uses that  `XSSFCellStyle` as the cell style of one cell. If you have 4 `XSSFColor`s, which shall be fill colors of cells, then you need creating 4  `XSSFCellStyle`s, each having one of the 4 `XSSFColor`s as the fill color. Then you can use those 4  different `XSSFCellStyle`s as cell styles for different cells in the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your showed code creates one `XSSFColor` from hex string and creates one `XSSFCellStyle` having that `XSSFColor` as the fill color. Then it uses that `XSSFCellStyle` as the cell style of one cell.

If you have 4 hex strings, which shall be fill colors of cells, then you need creating 4 `XSSFColors` for 4 `XSSFCellStyle`s, each `XSSFCellStyle` having one of the 4 `XSSFColors` as the fill foreground color. Then you can use those 4 different `XSSFCellStyle`s as cell styles for different cells in the sheet.

Of course if the hex strings are dynamically coming from outside, then the same hex string can come multiple times. Then you should not creating the same cell styles over and over again. There are limits for the count of cell styles  in `Excel`. See [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

The following example provides a method `setFillForegroundXSSFColor` which sets a given `XSSFColor` as the fill foreground color in cell style of given `XSSFCell`. It does not always creating a new cell style for this. Instead it checks whether there is a fitting cell style already in workbook, which is a combination of the current cell style of the cell plus required fill foreground color. If so, then that cell style is used. Only if not, a new cell style is created.

It also provides a method `getRGBFromHexString` which uses `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` to convert a hex string into a byte array. This uses string manipulation to support following hex string types for `RGB`: `FFFFFF`, `FFF`, `#FFFFFF` and `#FFF`.

Example code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

class CreateXSSFCellStyles {

 static byte[] getRGBFromHexString(String rgbString) {
  byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
  if (rgbString.startsWith("#")) rgbString = rgbString.substring(1);
  if (rgbString.length() == 3)
   rgbString =  rgbString.substring(0,1) + rgbString.substring(0,1)
              + rgbString.substring(1,2) + rgbString.substring(1,2)
              + rgbString.substring(2,3) + rgbString.substring(2,3);
  System.out.println(rgbString);
  try {
   rgb = Hex.decodeHex(rgbString);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   //decoder exception so byte[] rgb remains empty
  }
  return rgb;
 }

 static void setFillForegroundXSSFColor(XSSFCell cell, XSSFColor color, FillPatternType fillPatternType) {
  //get original cell style of cell
  XSSFCellStyle originalCellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
  //is there a fitting cell style already in workbook?
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
  for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumCellStyles(); i++) {
   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.getCellStyleAt(i);
   //cell style needs to fit requested fill foreground color and fill pattern type
   if (color.equals(cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor()) && cellStyle.getFillPattern() == fillPatternType) {
    //also cell style needs to fit all other cell style properties of original cell style
    if (
           cellStyle.getAlignment() == originalCellStyle.getAlignment()
        && cellStyle.getBorderLeft() == originalCellStyle.getBorderLeft()
        && cellStyle.getBorderTop() == originalCellStyle.getBorderTop()
        && cellStyle.getBorderRight() == originalCellStyle.getBorderRight()
        && cellStyle.getBorderBottom() == originalCellStyle.getBorderBottom()
        && cellStyle.getLeftBorderColor() == originalCellStyle.getLeftBorderColor()
        && cellStyle.getTopBorderColor() == originalCellStyle.getTopBorderColor()
        && cellStyle.getRightBorderColor() == originalCellStyle.getRightBorderColor()
        && cellStyle.getBottomBorderColor() == originalCellStyle.getBottomBorderColor()
        && cellStyle.getDataFormat() == originalCellStyle.getDataFormat()
        && cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor() == originalCellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor()
        && cellStyle.getFont() == originalCellStyle.getFont()
        && cellStyle.getHidden() == originalCellStyle.getHidden()
        && cellStyle.getIndention() == originalCellStyle.getIndention()
        && cellStyle.getLocked() == originalCellStyle.getLocked()
        && cellStyle.getQuotePrefixed() == originalCellStyle.getQuotePrefixed()
        && cellStyle.getReadingOrder() == originalCellStyle.getReadingOrder()
        && cellStyle.getRotation() == originalCellStyle.getRotation()
        && cellStyle.getShrinkToFit() == originalCellStyle.getShrinkToFit()
        && cellStyle.getVerticalAlignment() == originalCellStyle.getVerticalAlignment()
        && cellStyle.getWrapText() == originalCellStyle.getWrapText()
        ) {   
     cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
     System.out.println("fitting cell style found");
     return;
    }
   }
  }
  //no fitting cell style found, so create a new one
  XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(originalCellStyle);
  cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
  cellStyle.setFillPattern(fillPatternType);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
  System.out.println("new cell style created");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   headerCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
   headerCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
   font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
   headerCellStyle.setFont(font);
System.out.println(workbook.getNumCellStyles()); // 2 == default + header cell style

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
   XSSFCell cell;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cell = row.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue("Header " + (i+1));
    cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
   }

   String rgbS;
   byte[] rgbB;
   XSSFColor color;

   rgbS = "#FF0000";
   cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
   rgbB = getRGBFromHexString(rgbS);
   color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
   setFillForegroundXSSFColor(cell, color, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
System.out.println(workbook.getNumCellStyles()); // 3 == default + header cell style + this one new created

   rgbS = "0000FF";
   cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(3);
   rgbB = getRGBFromHexString(rgbS);
   color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
   setFillForegroundXSSFColor(cell, color, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
System.out.println(workbook.getNumCellStyles()); // 4 == default + header cell style + one from above + this one new created

   rgbS = "#F00";
   cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(5);
   rgbB = getRGBFromHexString(rgbS);
   color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
   setFillForegroundXSSFColor(cell, color, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
System.out.println(workbook.getNumCellStyles()); // 4 == default + header cell style + two from above, none new created

   rgbS = "#0000FF";
   cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(7);
   rgbB = getRGBFromHexString(rgbS);
   color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, null);
   setFillForegroundXSSFColor(cell, color, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
System.out.println(workbook.getNumCellStyles()); // 4 == default + header cell style + two from above, none new created

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AxelRichter it has solved my problem.